# Convert percentage to colors in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to generate color according to value from -1 to 1

the base colors are

My gaps are H:0 =1, H:60 = 0.5 , H:170= 0, H:200= -1 ( S:100 and L:50 ) 
[image]

I have found an [example](https://gist.github.com/mlocati/7210513#gistcomment-3060158) that convert percentage from green to red.

```js
function percentageToColor(percentage, maxHue = 200, minHue = 0) {
  const hue = percentage * (maxHue - minHue) + minHue;
  return `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
}
```

I would like to adapt it to my case by adding blue and use values from -1 to 1 by respecting the gaps equivalences as I mentioned above 
but I don't see how to do it.

**Upate**

I would like to use HSL/HSV

I'm looking for a way to find relation between percentage and `H` value

**Update 2**

I have Implemented @Muhammed B. Aydemir solution but visually I get colors ouf of the spectrum ( eventually black )

[image]

```
percentageToColor(pourcentage) {
let x = pourcentage.toFixed(2);
const colors = [[4, 189, 237], [10, 19, 0], [255, 248, 3], [253, 45, 45]];
const range = [0, 1, 1.5, 2];

const inBetween = (x, a, b) => x >= a && x <= b;

for (let i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
  const m = range[i];
  const n = range[i + 1];
  console.log(inBetween(x, m, n));
  if (inBetween(x, m, n)) {
    const c1 = colors[i];
    const c2 = colors[i + 1];
    const rangeDiff = n - m;

    const ratio = Math.abs((x - m) / rangeDiff);
    const [r, g, b] = c1.map((e, i) => {
      const e1 = c1[i];
      const e2 = c2[i];
      return Math.round(e1 + (e2 - e1) * ratio);
    });
    let color = [r, g, b].reduce((p, c) => `${p}${c.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')}`, '#');
    console.log([x, color]);
    return color;
  } else if (x > range[range.length - 1]) {
    console.log(x + 'red');
    return 'red';
  }
}
return 'OUT OF RANGE';
```

}

Comment: I have updated my question , I have deleted gradient percentages

Comment: Use [HSL/HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) instead of RGB

Comment: _"I'm looking for a way to find relation between percentage and H value"_ - `H` is a value between `0` and `360` degree. Converting `x%` with a given base should not be too difficult...

Comment: It's not exactly that, because values are between -1 and 1 and their color equivalence is not stepped equally  ( see my update )

Comment: In your implementation, you catch values that are bigger than your range, but you don't catch values that are below the range and as a result you get 'OUT OF RANGE' for every value below 0. Meaning the color falls back to the default one (which I assume is black).

Comment: Updated my answer to return 'white' for values that are below the range, and 'red' for values above the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:
You updated the question but the solution should be similar.

My solution would be as follows:

1. Find the interval in which the value x is in-between `(a,b = interval start and end)`
2. Get the colors for this interval `(c1, c2)`
3. Find the gap for red green and blue values for c1 and c2 `(ex. r_gap = r2-r1)`
4. Calculate `r = r1 + r_gap * |x - a / interval_length|`

And you should have your `r,g,b` values.

Example:

```js
const colors = [[4, 189, 237], [99, 19, 0], [255, 248, 3], [253, 45, 45]]
const range = [-1, 0, 0.5, 1]

const inBetween = (x, a, b) => x >= a && x <= b

const toRGB = x => {
  for (let i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    const m = range[i]
    const n = range[i + 1]
    if (inBetween(x, m, n)) {
      const c1 = colors[i]
      const c2 = colors[i + 1]
      const rangeDiff = n - m
      const ratio = Math.abs((x - m) / rangeDiff)
      const [r, g, b] = c1.map((e, i) => {
        const e1 = c1[i]
        const e2 = c2[i]
        return Math.round(e1 + (e2 - e1) * ratio)
      })
      console.log(r, g, b)
      return [r, g, b].reduce((p, c) => `${p}${c.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')}`, '#')
    }
  }
  if (x < range[0]) return 'white' // below range
  return 'red' // above range
}
    
const element = document.createElement('div');
let linearGradient = ''
for (let i = range[0]; i < range[range.length - 1]; i += 0.01)
  linearGradient += toRGB(i) + ','

element.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right,${linearGradient}${toRGB(range[range.length -1])})`;
document.body.append(element);
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: If I change ranges to `const range = [0, 1, 1.5, 2]`  are the colors generated the same than before ?

Comment: Yeah they should, you can even add or remove ranges,  but you have to change the colors accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Cristian Traìna, took it a step further